# How do I get my if else statements to work in C?

Tags: c, conditional-statements

Everything seems right but when I run this `if else` statement it always prints the question and the second statement automatically without asking question?

```
printf("How much money do you have?: ");
scanf("&d", &money);

if (money >= 25)
{
printf("Here is your food\n");
}

else (money <= 8);
{
printf("you dont have enough\n");
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have an error in your code. "&d" is not "%d". The proper scanf invocation is scanf("%d", &money) assuming money is a variable of type int. Please enable compiler warnings and resolve them.

Comment: Did you mean `else if(...)`? You also don't want the `;` at the end.

Comment: I guess I stared at it too long but the & was the mistake and works now with the %. Thanks for the help, now off to my other issues.

Comment: `else (money <= 8);` is not a valid statement, it should be `else if (money <= 8)` instead

Comment: @RemyLebeau It does happen to be valid. It just doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 2):

Else doesn't take an argument.

Else just means everything else other than `if` or any `else if` conditions you may have included.

Try using `else if` after an `if` statement in the same format that you have your `if`:

```
else if(money <= 8){ 
    printf("You are poor my man");
}
```

Also, worth considering what happens if the user has anywhere between 9 and 24 money? You may then want to implement an `else` statement to cover this range, as mentioned above else just simply handles every other case that wasn't picked up by your `if` and `else if`.

Answer (score 2):

See carefully . You have written wrong format specifier in your first 
Scanf statement . You have used "& " it should be "%d" . "&" is used to access address which is not required here . 
modify this statement `scanf("&d", &money);` 
to `scanf("%d", &money);`

Another reason why this thing is happening is because you had not handled all conditions. What if someone enter 16 or 10 .

Another thing, you should  not add any condition to else part . Else part are meant to handle every case except the if (or elseif) case. So even if you don't add any condition in else part it gonna work.
Here is corrected piece of code.

```
int main()
{
    int  money;
printf("How much money do you have?: ");
scanf("%d", &money);

if (money >= 25)
{
printf("Here is your food\n");
}

else
{
printf("you don't have enough\n");
}

return 0;
}
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/decision-making-c-c-else-nested-else/
```

Answer (score 2):

- Use `else if` if you have to use specific condition
- There was a syntax error when you taking a input using scanf method.

***Updated Code :***

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  int money;
  printf ("How much money do you have?: ");
  scanf ("%d", &money);  

  if(money >= 25)
    {

      printf("Here is your food\n");
    }

  else if(money <= 8)
  {

    printf("you dont have enough\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```